# How to get an int from a byte in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I retrieved the `backgroundTransparency` of a LWUIT Button , and it returns a `byte` datatype data. I want this `byte` variable to be converted to an `int` variable. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fernando's answer is 100% correct but is still slightly misleading e.g.:

```
 byte b = (byte)0xff;
 int intVar = b;

 boolean thisIsFalse = intVar == 0xff;
```

That might surprise most people at first glance but the logic is actually simple. 0xff is a negative number for a byte but a positive number for an int (this is also true in Java SE). The solution is to change the code from above to something that will convert to int "properly":

```
 int intVal = b & 0xff;
 boolean thisIsTrue = intVar == 0xff;
```

This will solve the issue there but you should still be aware that:

```
 boolean thisIsFalse = intVar == b;
 boolean thisIsTrue = intVar == (b & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 3):

J2ME is still Java:

```
int intVar = byteBar;
```